# How to get a reference to react component from a document event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a document mousemove event in my react component but I can't get access to a local variable in my class. How can I do this?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.name = 'hello';
            document.addEventListener ('mousemove', this.mousemoveListener, true);
        }

        mousemoveListener (e) {
            console.log(this.name); // returns undefined
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the context:

```
this.mousemoveListener = this.mousemoveListener.bind(this)
```

Add this line before you register the event listener.

I suggest that you learn about the oddity of `this` in JavaScript.

Comment: I added this.mousemoveListener = this.mousemoveListener.bind(this); as the last line in my constructor... didn't work. this.name still undefined in the mousemove function.

Comment: @foreyez You should add this line before passing the function to event listener.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Lexical scoping you can use arrow functions.
A nice pro of this approach is that you do not have to "remember" to bind "this" all the time

You can try to change

```
    mousemoveListener (e) {
        console.log(this.name); // returns undefined
    }
```

to this

```
    mousemoveListener = (e) => {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
```